# Image warping and morphing tool

Tags: images

I like collecting photos of places years apart so the viewer can see what has changed over the years. But no 2 photographs are identical in camera position so it undermines the quality of the result. For example:

[image]

I don't have the patience or knowledge to manually rotate, skew, crop, scale etc. photos to match as closely as possible (believe me I've tried with CSS!).

I bet there is software out there that makes it easier. I've probably seen it with old theme park machines or smartphone apps that age your face - which work well as long as you can identify key pixels in the image (e.g. eyes, nose, mouth...).

Does anyone know any such tools?

Comment: I asked about CSS3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216824/can-css-morph-images-by-pixel-mapping